# Как сравнить ввод с клавиатуры с текстом c++?

Tags: c++, if

Я не в курсе, как записать это корректно, если вы понимаете, о чём я.
До этого в шарпе работал, там так можно было)

```
if(scanf() == "да")
```

Comment: Напишите себе такую функцию(возвращающую std::string, а   в стандарте нет  такого удобства, потому что это редко кому  понадобится.

Answer (score 4):

Для C++

```
std::string s;
std::cin >> s;
if (s == "да") {
    std::cout << "YES" << std::endl;
}
```

https://ideone.com/1EcjAo

Для C++ без дополнительных переменных

```
if (*std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin) == "да") {
    std::cout << "YES" << std::endl;
}
```

https://ideone.com/KQTuSS

Для C, но в C++ работать тоже будет

```
char buf[100];
fgets(buf, 100, stdin);
if (strcmp(buf, "да") == 0) {
    printf("YES\n");
}
```

https://ideone.com/OUUGDc

Comment: А без переменных вообще можно реализовать? Чтобы просто сравнивался текст, введённый с клавиатуры с текстом в кавычках?

Comment: @onechess, обновил ответ. Но ничего страшного в отдельной переменной нет. Это C++, а не C# или python всё-таки.

Comment: Спасибо, хорошо

Comment: @onechess Ничего не мешает написать свой аналог `scanf`, возвращающий строку. Однако такая функция будет малополезна из-за посредственной производительности.